# How to change range in sub after copying and pasting data to new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a macro to copy data from one sheet and transpose and paste the data to another sheet as so:

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

    'Copy the data
    Sheets("Raw Data").Range("A4:A27").Copy
    'Transpose and paste data to new sheet
    Sheets("Distinct Users").Range("D6:AA6").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

I need to do this 31 times and I'm not quite sure how to do this.  I assume I need to use the .offset functionality in Range, but I am not sure how to do this...

for example, I need to change the initial range I've copied from ("A4:A27") to ("A28:A51") and then change the pasted range to ("D7:AA7").

I thought of creating a variable to define the starting cell, and another variable to define the ending cell of the range and then using offset to increase the offset inside of a loop.  My biggest problem is... I'm not sure how to define the starting cell and ending cell for my offset!  Also, I'm not sure if I can even do something like :

```
Dim lwrRange1 as Cell = "A4"
Dim uprRange1 as Cell = "A27"
Dim lwrRange2 as Cell = "D6"
Dim uprRange2 as Cell = "AA6"

Do While 1 <= 31
   'Copy the data
    Sheets("Raw Data").Range(lwrRange1:uprRange1).Copy
    'Transpose and paste data to new sheet
    Sheets("Distinct Users").Range(lwrRange2:uprRange2).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    lwrRange1 += 24
    uprRange1 += 24
    lwrRange2 += 1
    uprRange2 += 1
    i += 1
Loop
```

any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Range objects :

```
Dim SrcRg As Range
Dim DestRg As Range

Set SrcRg = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("A4:A27")
Set DestRg = Sheets("Distinct Users").Range("D6")

For i = 1 To 31
   'Copy the data
    SrcRg.Copy
    'Transpose and paste data to new sheet
    DestRg.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Set SrcRg = SrcRg.Offset(SrcRg.Rows.Count, 0)
    Set DestRg = DestRg.Offset(1, 0)
Next i
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try using a For loop like so:

```
    Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
Dim i As Integer
Dim rCopy As Range, rPaste As Range

Set rPaste = Sheets("Distinct Users").Range("D6:AA6")
Set rCopy = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("A4:A27")

For i = 0 To 30
    'Copy the data
    rCopy.Offset(rCopy.Rows.Count * i, 0).Copy
    'Transpose and paste data to new sheet
    rPaste.Offset(rPaste.Row + i, 0).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
Next i

End Sub
```